# Sonar Qube Java Custom Rules Template plugin not working

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

I want to add custom rules to my SonarQube installation 5.4.

Therefore I've downloaded the Java Test Plugin from "https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules" without any modification to the code.

I've imported the code to my Eclipse as a maven project and compiled it into a jar file.

After that, I switched into my SonarQube plugin folder and paste the plugin file.

Then I stop the SonarQube Service and restart it. Here comes my problem. My SonarQube does not start again. This is the errormessage from the logfile:

```
"ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance
of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: File is not a plugin. Please delete it and restart: 
/opt/sonar/extensions/plugins/customRuleExample.jar""
```

After I delete the file, SonarQuebe is able to restart again.

These are the Plugins I have installed right now:

- sonar-csharp-plugin-4.4.jar
- sonar-java-plugin-3.14.jar
- sonar-javascript-plugin-2.10.jar
- sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0.jar
- sonar-ojaudit-plugin-1.0.jar
- sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar

Do I have to make changes to the example code from git? Or am I missing something else?

Best regards,
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Please try to rebuild the plugin with command : `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-packaging-maven-plugin:1.12.1:sonar-plugin` and replace custom plugin jar. Also make sure you have sonar plugin configured in pom.xml with current version